# The value passed in must be an enum base or an underlying type for an enum, such as an Int32.Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7, enums

I keep getting this error on multiple pages once I have deployed my website on IIS7. It does not appear when I'm running on visual studio i.e. localhost.

Attached is the stack trace:
[image: Stack Trace]

erroneous code

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
       ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("OUT_RESULT", DbType.String);
       ObjectParameter outputdesc = new ObjectParameter("OUT_RESULTDESC", DbType.String);

       var deliveredShipments = db.PODDownload_SearchAllSP(Guid.Parse(Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString()), output, outputdesc);
       ViewBag.IsFirstLoad = true;
       ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
       return View(deliveredShipments.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: You should show the erroneous code or sample code that reproduces your issue.

Comment: @Sayse issue does not reproduce on development env.
I have attached the code that gives error.

Comment: You have attached code but it doesn't explain what line the error occurs on? The really small text on the stack trace seems to suggest the `toList` call if you zoom in to 150%. So the next question would be have you debugged into what `PODDownload_SearchAllSP` does/returns?

Comment: @Sayse The line which returns View(deliveredShipments.ToList()) is causing the problem.Bbut the thing is while debugging i get no errors it runs fine on my localhost and when i publish it to a server this shows up. Not only here but a couple of other pages too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This statement was causing the exception:

```
    ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("OUT_RESULT", DbType.String);
    ObjectParameter outputdesc = new ObjectParameter("OUT_RESULTDESC", DbType.String);
```

I changed it to the following:

```
    ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("OUT_RESULT", "");
    ObjectParameter outputdesc = new ObjectParameter("OUT_RESULTDESC", "");
```

This solved the issue, though i cannot figure out why this was causing problems once deployed and not on VS2010. I guess it has to do something with Entity Framework version.

Comment: I found the source of this error in my code by explicitly breaking on `ArgumentException` (check it in the "Exception Settings" pane in Visual Studio).  It was caused by `Enum.GetName` being passed a `string` for its `value` instead of a number or enum value.